# What is the best practice to define a session value for security?

Tags: php, session

I have a form where users can sign in. So I at first check the users email and password with the retrieved email and password from the database. Now I have to do a task to put a unique session value in a php session variable for each user. If I put the ID number of the user in the session variable, Is it a good practice? Now, review the following code.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['admin'] = $admin_id; 
?>
```

Comment: SO is not the "Code Review" SE ... oddly enough, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is ... however, this isn't a good fit there either, since there's nor really an awful lot of code to review here.

Comment: @AL MaMun. Its a good question. Continue to ask good questions. Lucas Meine answer addresses your concerns.  ... In fact CD001, SO is a code review site, unless you have some new definition on what review means.

Comment: @GetSet - not really, primarily SO is about fixing buggy code - not improving/reviewing code that works... that's sort of the difference between SO and Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can use sessions for that.

The session data is stored on the server, the client's browser is linked to it's session on the server based on the contents of a cookie containing only a reference ID.

There are techniques where a hacker can 'hijack' someone else's session, though. You should take a look at [Session hijacking attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack) to get familiarised with the methods that can be used to hijack a session and make sure your app does not allow any of those techniques, but other than that, what you are doing is a very common practice, specially in PHP.

And just to make this answer a little richer, you can study about [Token based authentication](https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/session-vs-token-based-authentication-11a6c5ac45e4), in case you want to try something new :)

Comment: If you understand what OP is asking, would you mind explaining it for the rest of us?

Comment: I can't speak for other people, but this question really reminds me the time I was learning how to code, where everything seems new. In my opinion, OP is trying to make a login system or something, and is wondering if storing the user id in the session is safe.

Comment: Safe from what exactly? This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: Just picture yourself as a beginner. Most of the times you don't even know what kind of threats you will face when you expose your first project to the internet. If I had to guess, OP just wanted to have some general guidance from more experienced people, and that's exactly why I linked some external stuff so he can learn and feel more confident about his code :)

Comment: thanks for all comments.